# Silverlight/WPF charting toolkit. Can I change frequency of tick marks on CategoryAxis?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, charts, silverlight-toolkit, wpftoolkit

There is Interval property on LinearAxis but none on CategoryAxis. I need to control frequency of tick marks on X axis.

The native logic does so many marks that I cant read even if I stretch the chart across 3 wide monitors!!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions...

1.) CategoryAxis has a AxisLabelStyle property which you can use to set in a Style with a smaller FontSize, or a more condensed FontFamily

2.) CategoryAxis also has MajorTickMarkStyle which you can use to set the Line Stroke brush or StrokeThickness.  Use a StrokeThickness of 0 to hide them.

3.) Maybe you can find a way to get a changethe Width of the AxisLabel's container and make the label text wrap.

Good luck
Jim McCurdy