# Tick marks for X-axis in WPF toolkit chart

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, toolkit

```
<Window x:Class="tradtest.chart"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"

Title="chart" Height="300" Width="500">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SimpleLineSeriesStyle" TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
    </Style>


</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <charting:Chart x:Name="chart1" >
        <charting:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}"

                DependentValuePath="Value"

                IndependentValuePath="Key"

                Title="Pet Preference" IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    </charting:Chart>

</Grid>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace tradtest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for chart.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class chart : Window
    {
        void AddSeries(string title, KeyValuePair<string, decimal>[] data, SolidColorBrush linecolor)
        {
            LineSeries ls = new LineSeries();
            ls.DependentValuePath = "Value";
            ls.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
            ls.ItemsSource = data;
            ls.Title = title;
            Style dpstyle = ls.DataPointStyle;
            //Style tmp1 = this.Resources["SimpleLineSeriesStyle"] as Style;
            Style tmp1 = new Style();
            tmp1.Setters.Add(new Setter(LineDataPoint.BackgroundProperty, linecolor));
            tmp1.Setters.Add(new Setter(LineDataPoint.WidthProperty, 0.0));
            tmp1.Setters.Add(new Setter(LineDataPoint.HeightProperty, 0.0));
            //wi
            //dpstyle = tmp1;
            ls.DataPointStyle = tmp1;
            //SetterBaseCollection sr = dpstyle.Setters;
            //SetterBase sb = new Setter(Background, (object)Brushes.AliceBlue);
            chart1.Series.Add(ls);
        }
        public chart(KeyValuePair<string, decimal>[] spreadseries,
            KeyValuePair<string, decimal>[] meanspreadseries,
            KeyValuePair<string, decimal>[] enterlongseries,
            KeyValuePair<string, decimal>[] entershortseries,
            KeyValuePair<string, decimal>[] exitlongseries,
            KeyValuePair<string, decimal>[] exitshortseries)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            chart1.Series.Clear();
            AddSeries("Current Spread", spreadseries, Brushes.MediumPurple);
            AddSeries("Mean Spread", meanspreadseries, Brushes.Black);
            AddSeries("Enter Long Spread", enterlongseries, Brushes.Red);
            AddSeries("Enter Short  Spread", entershortseries, Brushes.Red);
            AddSeries("Exit Long Spread", exitlongseries, Brushes.Orange);
            AddSeries("Exit Short Spread", exitshortseries, Brushes.Orange);

        }
    }
}
```

I have attached my code above.
I am not able to remove X-axis tick marks. can someone please advice?

Comment: I can't copy image, following is URL of the chart : http://www.quantcode.com/uploads/img4d49673d432fb.png

Comment: There will be a property on the Chart - I don't have it installed on this machine so I can't check, but Intellisense should show you all the properties you can set.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395774/silverlight-wpf-charting-toolkit-can-i-change-frequency-of-tick-marks-on-categor for some hints - not a concrete answer though.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the entire X-axis like this:

```
<charting:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
    <charting:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</charting:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
```

add it to your `charting:LineSeries` element or in code:

```
series.IndependentAxis = new CategoryAxis { Orientation = AxisOrientation.X, Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! Unfortunately, I am creating the lineseries programatically. I tried setting the style programatically. But ls.IndependentAxis is returning me null in the above code and I can't mimic the above XAML in code.

Comment: Thanks for the example code. I tried it, but am getting an excpetion below when I call Show() on the window containing the chart : "Assigned independent axis cannot be used. This may be due to an unset Orientation property for the axis."

Comment: Since you have strings on the X-axis, use `CategoryAxis` instead of `LinearAxis`.

Answer (score 0):

All series are sharing the same X-axis right? so you can add a generic X-axis (category as suggested is better if you working with string indipendent values) and set the AxisLabelStyle to display or not the content styling the content template. I use this solution and series added runtime will use the existent X-axis you add.

HTH