# WPF Toolkit hide "Key" value in Area Chart

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I have a chart that displays `CPU usage`. It uses following code to add values and refresh:

```
cPUChartValueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(i.ToString(), iCPUtotal_usage));
CPU_Chart.DataContext = cPUChartValueList;
CPU_Chart.Refresh();
```

In this string value there are recorded seconds and int value contais `CPU usage`.

Chart is rendered correctly but I can't get rid of this `Key` string value from showing in the chart. Im sitting 2 hours on this and still can't find a solution.

[image: CPU Usage]

Everything works but I just can't hide "seconds". If I add new X-axis and set it to hidden then `WPFToolkit` adds new axis with these seconds on the top (what is going on?)

[image: Second Chart]

I've run out of ideas. I will be grateful if You could provide me a way to disable this.

Waiting for any help
Best Regards

Comment: Can you post your xaml please?

Comment: Of course, here it is  [link](http://pastebin.com/j2wEdqB9)

Comment: I found out using XAML Spy that this axis with strings is "CategoryAxis" and it's added dynamically by WPFToolkit. Any way to disable it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tick marks for X-axis in WPF toolkit chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891841/tick-marks-for-x-axis-in-wpf-toolkit-chart)
That's what are you looking for

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for the answer. If I add this code
[code]<chartingToolkit:AreaSeries.IndependentAxis>
                    <chartingToolkit:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </chartingToolkit:AreaSeries.IndependentAxis>[/code]
Then this "seconds" axis hides but There are no values on the CPU usage axis. It's empty. It seems that this affect both axises, one with strings and one with int too.
Still looking for a way to disable just "seconds" axis, not the int one

Comment: Temporary fix for all those that have same problems. Set Foreground to Transparent and set FontSize to 1. It's hidden and very small now but still takes some space.